# Can we use Teradata as a backend database while developing sails.js app?

Tags: sails.js

We have to built an app using sails.js, while we need to know that can sails.js support connectivity with teradata database or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am afraid - NOT.
https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline

> Community Adapters
>
> PostgreSQL - 0.9+ compatible MySQL - 0.9+ compatible MongoDB - 0.9+
>   compatible Memory - 0.9+ compatible Disk - 0.9+ compatible Microsoft
>   SQL Server Redis Riak IRC Twitter JSDom Neo4j OrientDB ArangoDB Apache
>   Cassandra GraphQL Solr Apache Derby